# Unix: How to sort a dat file and keep original line numbers

Tags: sorting, unix, line-numbers

I have a large data file containing over a thousand entries. I would like to sort them but maintain the original line numbers. For instance,

```
1:100
2:120
3:10
4:59
```

Where the first number is the line number, not saved in the data file, separated by a colon from the real number. I would like to sort it and keep the line numbers bound to their original lines, with an output of:

```
2:120
1:100
4:59
3:10
```

If possible, I would like to do this without creating another file, and numbering them by hand is not an option for the data size I'm using.

Comment: `sort -k=POS1,POS2` should be exactly what you're looking for.  See "man sort" for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Given a file `test.dat`:

```
100
120
10
59
```

... the command:

```
$ cat -n test.dat | sort --key=2 -nr
     2  120
     1  100
     4  59
     3  10
```

... gives the output that you seem to be looking for (though with the fields delimited by tabs, which is easily changed if necessary):

```
$ cat -n test.dat | sort --key=2 -nr | sed -e's/\t/:/'
     2:120
     1:100
     4:59
     3:10
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you and paulsm4 for the 'key' command. I had completely forgotten to shift the sort to the second column and I feel a bit silly!

Comment: Glad to help. If this answer solves the problem for you, please mark it as "accepted" so that others won't come to your question thinking you still require a solution.